# Adjust for large figure size in Shiny RMarkdown report

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown

I am developing a Shiny RMarkdown report that includes a section that allows users to create different ridgeline plots by grouping the dataset based on different variables (e.g., subject, course, assignment). However, some variables only have a few groups (e.g. subject) while others have many groups (e.g. assignment).  For variables with many groups the resulting graph becomes unreadable so I would like to either increase the figure size or allow users to scroll down the graph somehow.  Does anyone have any suggestions how I might do this? (example Rmd file with dummy data below)

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "R User"
date: "9/7/2021"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

# example data
df <- data.frame(
  subject = c(rep("A", 1000), rep("B", 1000), rep("C", 1000)),
  course = rep(paste0("Course ", as.character(1:300)), 10),
  value = rnorm(3000)
)
```

## Modify figure size

I would like to modify the figure size so the ridgelines are still readable when grouped by course, either by making the figure size larger overall or allowing the user to scroll down the figure.

```{r, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("group", label = "Group",
              choices = c("subject", "course"))
)

renderPlot({
  ggplot(df, aes(y = !!as.symbol(input$group), x = value)) +
    ggridges::geom_density_ridges(color = "grey95", fill = "grey50", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_boxplot(fill = "grey95", color = "grey40", width = 0.2, outlier.shape = NA) +
    labs(y = "") +
    theme_minimal()
})
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never followed up with the answer I figured out... here's an approach that doesn't require adding a slider for anyone else facing the same problem in the future, (1) using my example and (2) using a more minimal version with built-in datasets:

**Version 1**

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "R User"
date: "9/7/2021"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
# example data
df <- data.frame(
  subject = c(rep("A", 1000), rep("B", 1000), rep("C", 1000)),
  course = rep(paste0("Course ", as.character(1:300)), 10),
  value = rnorm(3000)
)
```

## Modify figure size

I would like to modify the figure size so the ridgelines are still readable when grouped by course, either by making the figure size larger overall or allowing the user to scroll down the figure.

```{r, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("group", label = "Group",
              choices = c("subject", "course"))
)

plot_height <- reactive({
  df %>%
    pull(get(input$group)) %>%
    unique() %>%
    length()
})

renderPlot({
  ggplot(df, aes(y = !!as.symbol(input$group), x = value)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme_minimal()
}, height = function() { 50 * plot_height() })
```
````

**Version 2**

````
---
title: "Dynamic Plot Height"
author: "Natalie O'Shea"
date: '2022-05-31'
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("grouping", label = "Select grouping:", 
              choices = c("supp", "dose"))
)

plot_height <- reactive({
  ToothGrowth %>%
    pull(get(input$grouping)) %>%
    unique() %>%
    length()
})

renderPlot({
  ToothGrowth %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = len)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    facet_wrap(~get(input$grouping), ncol = 1)
}, height = function() { 100 * plot_height() })
```
````

Answer (score 0):

We can add a slider bar to let users choose the height of the plot, so when they think it is too squeezed, they can increase the height.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "R User"
date: "9/7/2021"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
# example data
df <- data.frame(
  subject = c(rep("A", 1000), rep("B", 1000), rep("C", 1000)),
  course = rep(paste0("Course ", as.character(1:300)), 10),
  value = rnorm(3000)
)
```

## Modify figure size

I would like to modify the figure size so the ridgelines are still readable when grouped by course, either by making the figure size larger overall or allowing the user to scroll down the figure.

```{r, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("group", label = "Group",
              choices = c("subject", "course")),
  sliderInput("p_height", "Plot height", value = 600, min = 400, max = 1000, step = 50, round = TRUE)
)

renderPlot({
  ggplot(df, aes(y = !!as.symbol(input$group), x = value)) +
    ggridges::geom_density_ridges(color = "grey95", fill = "grey50", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_boxplot(fill = "grey95", color = "grey40", width = 0.2, outlier.shape = NA) +
    labs(y = "") +
    theme_minimal()
}, height = exprToFunction(input$p_height))
```
````

Change the default `value`, `min` `max` to a number you want, unit in pixels.

[image]